# Python ValueError: Inserting a list of values using df.loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, computer-vision, pytorch

I have a dataframe `df` with paths of images. I am performing object detection and want to save the names of the detected objects in a new column (named `objects`) of the dataframe.

However the code works fine when only 1 object is detected, when there is a list of multiple objects the code gives an error.

`ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value`

I think there is some problem with my way of inserting values in the dataframe. I have actually created an empty column first and then using loop inserting vaues in the `objects` column.

**Code**

```
train_image_paths = 'data/train_images/' + df['image']    # train_images is the folder containing images and 
                                                          #  df['image'] contains all image paths

df['objects'] = ''     # Creating an empty column for storing detected objects

for idx, img in enumerate(train_image_paths):
    ..
    #object detection code    # Performs object detection and 
                              # stores the detected objects in a list named detected_objects
    ..
    
    df.loc[idx, 'objects'] = detected_objects   # Adding the detected objects to the dataframe
    
return df
```

**Output of df.info()**

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 34250 entries, 0 to 34249
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   image   34250 non-null  object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 267.7+ KB
```

Comment: I think you should create a new list or `Pandas Series()` then append it to the dataframe.

Comment: Can you implement this in the Answer section? I have tried multiple ways nut go one or the other error.

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: @jezrael I have added the output. This is the original dataframe, in which I create an empty column and try to store detected outputs row wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create new list or `Pandas Series` then append it to dataframe.

```py
train_image_paths = 'data/train_images/' + df['image']    # train_images is the folder containing images and 
                                                          #  df['image'] contains all image paths

objects = []     # Creating an empty column for storing detected objects

for idx, img in enumerate(train_image_paths):
    ..
    #object detection code    # Performs object detection and 
                              # stores the detected objects in a list named detected_objects
    ..
    
    objects.append(detected_objects)   # Adding the detected objects to the dataframe


df['objects'] = objects
return df
```

Here is the references: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-pandas/

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with custom function:

```
def func(x):
    train_image_paths = 'data/train_images/' + x
    #object detection code 
    return detected_objects


df['objects'] = df['image'].apply(func)
```